# LLVM address sanitizer with CMake

Tags: c++, cmake, llvm-clang, address-sanitizer

I am trying to compile the simplest executable using clang with -fsanitize=address option. It's very simple to do that using clang directly. But my point is to do it through CMake.

There is how I am doing it.
CMakeLists.txt file:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.5.1 FATAL_ERROR)
project(TestSanitizer VERSION 0.1.0 LANGUAGES CXX)
add_executable(Test main.cpp)
target_compile_options(Test PUBLIC
    -std=c++17
    -Werror
    -Weverything
    -Wno-c++98-compat
    -Wno-c++98-c++11-c++14-compat
    -Wno-c++98-compat-pedantic
    -fsanitize=address)
```

main.cpp:

```
int main(int, const char**) { return 0; }
```

configure and make using bash script (config_gen_build.sh):

```
if [ -d "bin" ]; then
    rm -rf bin
fi

mkdir bin
cd bin

#config and gen
export CC=/usr/bin/clang-5.0
export CXX=/usr/bin/clang++-5.0
cmake ./../

#build
make
```

Finally, the error I am getting:
[image]

What's wrong here?
Should I link with some library?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The easiest way to link with the address sanitizer is to specify `-fsanitize=address` as a linker, as well as a compiler, option. This causes clang or gcc to pass the correct libraries and flags to the linker.

Comment: can you also share how and what flags to use to add the same to CMake file

Answer (score 4):

I believe you forgot to pass `-fsanitize` to the link options as the other answer mentioned. So you need *both*:

```
target_compile_options(Foo PUBLIC -fsanitize=address)
target_link_options(Foo PUBLIC -fsanitize=address)
```

Alternatively, to enable this for you entire project, you can use the following CMake directives at the beginning of your project file:

```
add_compile_options(-fsanitize=address)
add_link_options(-fsanitize=address)
```